# EC2 r3 8xlarge EBS limit

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

We have a r3.8xlarge SQL 2014 instance. We have attached 2 EBS volumes (each of 5 TB) to this instance.
We need another 5TB volume that we plan to attach to this SQL instance.

Is there a limit on how many EBS volumes can be attached or total EBS storage limit that can be attached to an EC2 e.g. not exceeding 15 TB or some best practice?

For our scenario, we expect the instance to be running only against one EBS volume at a given time.

thanks

Comment: [EC2 instance Volume limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html)

Comment: Yes that answers volume count limit. Need to now source the EBS storage limit per instance.Thanks